# Auto-generate ID Number VB.Net Not Working [Access DB]

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I've been looking around the internet (and also here), and I found one code that might work for me. However, it doesn't increment and I don't know what else is wrong. Here's the code, kindly help me sort this out:

```
Private Function GenID() As String
        Dim dr As OleDbDataReader
        Dim com As OleDbCommand
        Dim value As String = "2021000"

        Try
            con.Open()
            com = New OleDbCommand("SELECT MAX(studno) FROM record", con)
            dr = com.ExecuteReader()
            If dr.HasRows Then
                dr.Read()
                value = dr.Item("studno")
            End If

            value += 1

            If value <= 9 Then                'Value is between 0 and 10
                value = "202100" & value
            ElseIf value <= 99 Then        'Value is between 9 and 100
                value = "20210" & value
            ElseIf value <= 999 Then        'Value is between 999 and 1000
                value = "2021" & value
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)

        End Try

        Return value
    End Function

    Private Sub addRecords_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        studno.Text = GenID()
    End Sub
```

Comment: Activate: `Option Strict On` then you can see your issues. The `value` variable is a `String` so  `value += 1` is wrong. Use `Using` directives for DB Objects/Helpers. Remove `If` conditions and use a numeric `variable.ToString(“000”)` or a String `variable.PadLeft(“0”, 3)` instead. Hoping that studno is a numeric Type Of Data in your Db

Answer (score 0):

You are only retrieving a single piece of data, so `DataReader` isn't necessary.
Use `ExecuteScalar` which returns the the first column of the first row in the result set. It returns an `Object` so it requires the `CInt`.

You need to be careful with datatypes. `String`s and `Integer`s are two different types. One cannot be assigned to the other without conversion. You can't do arithmetic with `String`s. I created two different variables. One for the `Integer`, `value` and one for the `String`, `StrValue`. You are able to concatenate an `Integer` to a `String` with the `&`. The ampersand tells the compiler to call `.ToString` on the `Integer` variable, `value`.

I have demonstrated the use of `Using...End Using` which ensures that your database objects are closed and disposed. The comma at the end of the first line of the `Using` means that the next line is included in the `Using`. In this case, the command.

If all you are doing is showing a message box in the `Catch`, then do it in the user interface code. If the `Function` creates an exception, you will not want to show the result. So, the `Return` statement exits the `Sub`. Only after we have successfully completed the `Try...End Try`, do we assign the `NewID` to the text box.

```
Private ConStr As String = "Your connection string"
Private Function GenID() As String
    Dim value As Integer
    Using con As New OleDbConnection(ConStr),
            com = New OleDbCommand("SELECT MAX(studno) FROM record", con)
        con.Open()
        value = CInt(com.ExecuteScalar)
    End Using
    value += 1
    Dim StrValue As String
    If value <= 9 Then                'Value is between 0 and 10
        StrValue = "202100" & value
    ElseIf value <= 99 Then        'Value is between 9 and 100
        StrValue = "20210" & value
    ElseIf value <= 999 Then        'Value is between 999 and 1000
        StrValue = "2021" & value
    Else
        StrValue = "0"
    End If
    Return StrValue
End Function

Private Sub addRecords_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim NewID As String = ""
    Try
        NewID = GenID()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Return
    End Try
    studno.Text = NewID
End Sub
```

This method will not work well in a multiuser environment. If 2 users are trying to get the next id at the same time a duplicate id will result. It can be avoided by adding a year column in the database and using an autoincrement field for `studno`.